# Bunimovich stadium bouncing ball

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, elliptic-pde

[image]http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/07/07/hassells-proof-of-scarring-for-the-bunimovich-stadium/
I cannot relate how the eigenfunctions normalizaed correspond to the probabality distribution of the particles.Can anyone explain this to me.

Comment: to "probabality distribution of the particles" : There is only 1 particle (the ball).

Comment: that's what it means